# Prestashop 1.7.1 - How to get product price with taxes (VAT)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

If I do this in a custom module:

```
<div class="product-price-and-shipping">
    <span class="price"> 
        {Tools::displayPrice($product.price)}
    </span>
</div>
```

I get the price without taxes (+21% VAT).

How can I get the product price with taxes included (+21% VAT)

Comment: do you override getProducts() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a rule or a php misbehaviour somewhere because it's $product.price for full price and $product.price_tax_exc without VAT for product lists.

Comment: I probably overrided getProducts method as stated in the comment. I hardcoded a fix multiplying by 1.21.